# c++ coverage setup with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have CMake project that sometimes may use clang, sometimes it may use gcc, sometimes it may use MSVC.
Does CMake provide some generic way to enable coverage generation, or do I need to do if else by myself(compiler flags for gcc and clang differ, and MSVC does not have coverage)?

Comment: I'd say that you need to do all the stuff yourself even if cmake does provide some generic way to handle that (e.g. specify dialect flags for all the supported compilers instead of relying on `CXX_STANDARD` magic macro to do it for you). As for MSVC coverage, you may want to check [OpenCppCoverage](https://github.com/OpenCppCoverage/OpenCppCoverage/wiki)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no central `cmake` option to handle such a situation, but some solutions could be:

- Don't do anything. Collect coverage statistics with [`kcov`](https://simonkagstrom.github.io/kcov/), which doesn't require special compiler flags.
- Add a build configuration alongside the usual `Debug`, `RelWithDebugInfo` and so on. Then, select this build configuration only when it makes sense, i.e., when compiling with `clang` or `gcc`. Like this:

  ```
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" CACHE STRING
      "Build options: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel Coverage." FORCE)

  # Use generator expression to enable flags for the Coverage profile
  target_compile_options(yourExec
      $<$<CONFIG:COVERAGE>:--coverage>)

  # Don't forget that the linker needs a flag, too:
  target_link_libraries(yourExec
      PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:COVERAGE>:--coverage>)
  ```

  When you need to dispatch further on the compiler type, you can use generator expressions, too.

  ```
  $<$<OR:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:AppleClang>,
      $<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>>:-someOtherFlag>
  ```

  but as far as I know, there are no real differences between `clang` and `gcc` with respect to coverage flags.
- Don't add another build configuration, just define the above flags for the build configuration you intend to use for coverage reports, probably `Debug`. Then, it's obviously necessary to exclude `MSVC`.

  ```
  target_compile_options(yourExec
      $<$<AND:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>,$<NOT:CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>:--coverage>)

  target_link_libraries(yourExec
      PRIVATE $<$<AND:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>,$<NOT:CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>:--coverage>)
  ```

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html seems unsupported by gcc, and acording to clang people it is the best coverage option.

Comment: Good point, I didn't know about those option. Since which `clang` version is it available?

Comment: IDK, but I know Clang 6.0 has it